# Convert C++/CLI delegate^ to long and back

Tags: delegates, c++-cli

How can I convert PaintDelegate^ to a long to be sent as the refCon param so that once inside the TrackTransferCB I can convert it back and invoke it?  The long it is converted to doesn't have to mean anything as long as I can convert it back to the delegate.

This is the general idea:

```
PaintDelegate^ paintDel = ...;
refCon = (long)paintDel;  // This conversion doesn't work

...

static OSErr TrackTransferCB(Track t, long refCon) {
    (PaintDelegate^)refCon->Invoke();  // This conversion doesn't work
}
```

Which conversions will work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate objects are garbage collected objects, just like any other non-value type in .NET.  Which means that the garbage collector can move them.  Which means that getting their address cannot work, the address will change when the GC compacts the heap.

I'm guessing you need to do this to pass unmanaged code some kind of reference to the delegate.  A handle is the typical solution.  Just keep a counter around that you increment each time you create a new object.  Store it in a `Dictionary<int, PaintDelegate^>^` and pass the counter value to the unmanaged code.

Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate() is another approach, the unmanaged code can now directly invoke the delegate target.  Not a long but a void*.  You do however still have to store the delegate object somewhere safe so it won't get garbage collected.  I recommend the former.

Comment: It's actually running in managed code and being called from unmanaged code.  In order for this to work it's a static function, so I want to call a non-static function to have access to private non-static members.  Am I allowed to pin a delegate's location?

Comment: That's what GetFunctionPointerForDelegate does, it creates a little thunk to store the target instance reference.  Pinning is not disallowed but you'll risk being eaten by goto raptors.

Comment: Performance is critical in this function since it's called in realtime for every frame of a video.  Could dictionary lookup be fast enough?

Comment: You won't have more than, what, 60 frames per second?  Keep your eye on the ball, you do *millions* of dictionary lookups in that time.  Don't do it for every pixel.